# How to prevent registry key from being abbreviated on 64-bit Windows

Tags: inno-setup, registrykey

While debugging a browser plugin I noticed that the location of the resource was being abbreviated in Windows 64-bit registry keys. When the registry entry was manually edited to use the long-form path to the resource the plugin started to be recognized.

The DLL is installed to CommonFiles64 and the registry key was added to WOW64 by auto-registering the DLL using InnoSetup.

My question: how to prevent regsvr32 from abbreviating the path to the resource?

For example: I need to prevent the abbreviation of someNicePlugin.dll to someNic~.dll

Comment: What I need to prevent is the abbreviation of someNicePlugin.dll to someNic~.dll because this is what autoregistering 64-bit from Inno does.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for isn't "abbreviation", but rather "shortening" to an [8.3 filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)

Comment: I wonder what would happen if the full path to the resource were shorter. In other words, I wonder if it's a "64 bit" issue, or a "path length" issue?

Comment: The path part could not be shorter, but the filename is only 2 letters longer than the 32-bit version which has 13 letters anyway. It's only the 64-bit path that gets shortened.

Comment: BTW, what specific problem is this phenomenon causing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegSvr32 doesn't write registry values; it merely loads the DLL and invokes functions the DLL exports. It's those functions that write the values. So it's those functions that need to be changed.

Comment: If the DLLs in question were produced with Delphi, you might be interested in this QC report: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=118309